# Visual Studio 2015: MVC 6 Scaffolding switched to using IActionResult intead of ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

I've just installed VS 2015 and I noticed a few changes in the auto-scaffolding of MVC6. I am curious why Microsoft made those changes, as I think if they decided to do some there might be some benefits that I may not know of.

> In VS 2013, the MVC 5 Auto-Scaffolding always used: ActionResult
>
> In VS 2015 the MVC 6 Auto-Scaffolding switched to using: IActionResult

In VS 2015 I notice that the Microsoft team prefer not to do this anymore:

```
 public class Test{
     private int i;
     public Test (int i){
         this.i = i;
     }
 }
```

While in all generated classes I saw that they did:

```
 public class Test{
     private int _i;
     public Test (int i){
         _i = i;
     }
 }
```

If it is just the matter of coding style, it's fine I will immediately lose my interests in known why they changed this, but if there is any logical explanation behind this I can't wait to know what that is.

Comment: Not sure about your `Test` question, but as for `ActionResult` vs `IActionresult` - I assume they follow convention and `IActionResult` is an interface.. so you gain all the advantages of coding to an interface rather than a class - namely being able to change the return type without knowing what it be until runtime.  Say for example `JsonResult` implemented `IActionResult` - then you could scaffold the same code as above, but easily change the return type from `ActionResult` to `JsonResult` without changing the method signature.

Comment: they are abstracting the actionresult away so there is no concrete implmentatio so you can use any class as long as it inherits from the IActionresult interface

Comment: I believe this are 2 questions. First the one about IActionResult, second the one about the private variable naming convention. You should split that up.

Comment: The two Test classes produce identical CLR code (except for metadata saying "there is a field named _i" instead of "there is a field named i"). While the change is trivial, I like it -- the underscore convention gets rid of a lot of hard-to-detect bugs where you have `i = value` but need `this.i = value`.

Answer (score 3):

As far as your ActionResult question is concerned, in previous ASP.NET, MVC controllers used the System.Web.MVC.Controller Parent class and a Web API controller used the System.Web.Http.ApiController Parent class.

But in ASP.NET 5 MVC 6, they have merged both in a single web app. So now there is only 1 controller class Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controller class as a base for both of them.
Now to distinguish bethween them, when used as an MVC controller, the IActionResult might be a view. When used as a Web API controller, the IActionResult might be data (JSON/XML). The same controller might have actions that return both views and data.